# AWK Column not printing at all when others do?

Tags: awk

I'm having a very weird issue where I'm working with two files

My awk script:

Its meant to match in both first fields of both files where rows are equal. Then do other conditionals on the other fields and check if they match. This seems to be working fine for all other fields however the second field, $2, of the first file fails to be populated.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { 
    FS=OFS=","
    total = 0; 
}

FNR==NR{
    reg[$1] = $1;
    reg_s[$2] = $2;
    account[$3] = $3;
    site_name[$4] = $4;
    next;
}
{
    if ($1 in reg)
        if ( (($2 != "Yes") && (reg_s[$2] == "3")) || (($2 == "Yes") && (reg_s[$2] != "3")) ) {
            print  "Status Error";
            total++;
        }           
}
END { 
    print " - DONE - " total" Errors"
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

file1:

```
abcd,3,Paper,go
abcde,3,stapler,staples
abb,0,pencil,sharpener
```

file2:

```
abcd,Yes,Paper,go
abcde,Yes,stapler,staples
abb,No,pencil,sharpener
```

to run it:

```
awk -f myscript.awk file1 file2
```

Comment: you're checking `reg_s[$2] == "3"` but you assigned `reg_s[$2]=$2`, so the contents of the array index and field value are equal as set in the first file.  There is no `reg_s["Yes"]`. Perhaps it will help if you explain what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, so basically if the $2 in the second file is "Yes" and  the $2 in the first file is not "3", then I want to do an action.

Comment: so should reg_s exist outside of FNR==NR? since the second field is 3 in the first file and yes in the other?

Comment: When processing the second file `$2` value is "Yes/No", your array doesn't have a value indexed for this key.  Please review my answer and perhaps you can use the ideas/approach there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can use...

```
$ join -t, <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | 
  awk -F, '($2==3) != ($5=="Yes"){count++} END{print count+0}'
```

join the files by the key (need to be sorted first), count the matching records.  Note that `!a && b || a && !b` is the definition of xor and can be written simply as `a!=b` as I did above.

This should print zero.  (`count+0` is to initialize the value as a numeric in case it never satisfies the condition)

Answer (score 0):

Run the script with the following debug modifications. It debugs the first part, when you populate the arrays:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    total = 0;
}

FNR==NR{
    reg[$1] = $1;
    reg_s[$2] = $2;
    account[$3] = $3;
    site_name[$4] = $4;
    next;
}
{
    print "----------reg----------------"
    for (key in reg) { print key " : " reg[key] }
    print "----------reg_s--------------"
    for (key in reg_s) { print key " : " reg_s[key] }
    print "----------account------------"
    for (key in account) { print key " : " account[key] }
    print "-----------site_name---------"
    for (key in site_name) { print key " : " site_name[key] }
    print "============================"
}
```

The output is:

```
----------reg----------------
abcd : abcd
abb : abb
abcde : abcde
----------reg_s--------------
0 : 0
3 : 3
----------account------------
stapler : stapler
Paper : Paper
pencil : pencil
-----------site_name---------
staples : staples
go : go
sharpener : sharpener
============================
```

As you can see, all arrays have three items except reg_s, and it is because reg_s gets assigned twice with the same key "3", and in awk when an array item is assigned with an existing key, it doesn't create a new array item, instead it replace the prevoius value.

That is why you have all arrays with three elements, because they have all differente keys, except this one, reg_s, which was populated using only two different keys, "3", and "0".

Hope this help, I can edit and elaborate some more if you need.

Comment: Can't provide a real solution because it depends on the logic of what you are trying to achieve with the data, but in my answer I clarified what is wrong with the script.